# Class not found com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql

I got this error

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

but I have this class in my `pom.xml` and its in my `maven dependencies` folder. Each time I added some lib to `pom.xml` everything was ok till now I even try to do maven -> update project but it didn't help

Im using Eclipse Juno

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "*****");     
return c;
```

Edit
`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.21</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: show your pom.xml. Do you create web or desktop app?

Comment: Ensure dependency is in 'compile' scope and type='jar'. Try also creating null reference in code: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver driver = null to check if it is resolved.

Comment: Im learning how to create  servlets

Comment: scope="runtime" should be enough as it is only needed during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more straitforward way to get a connection:

Connection c = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver().connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root", null);

There will be no puzzles like ClassNotFoundException

Comment: this may be more straightforward but it's certainly much less elegant. your way couples the driver implementation much more tightly to the project, as it needs to be in import statements.

Comment: but your code is coupled to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", isn't it? Anyway, I just wanted to show that DriverManager is not the only way to get a Connection

Comment: you're right if you count the string occurrence as coupling. but just imagine that string being in a config file and it's as loose coupled as possible. but true, there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start the server? How do you do deployment? From inside eclipse? Check the deployed folder if the jar is there. If you're using eclipse it will be in:

`${workspace}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib` 
(if using windows)

Your maven config and code look fine, I would say it's a deployment problem.

Comment: Im using `ubuntu 12.04` and under this path i dont have `lib` directory only `web.xml` file, Now I also have `HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` such error

Comment: i think your setup might be wrong. you should have at least a classes directory there... what eclipse plugins (including version) do you use? don't list all of them, just the ones concerning maven and web tools platform.

Comment: `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/servlets` in this direcotry I have `META-INF` and `WEB-INF` but inside WEB-INF I dont have lib directory only `classes` and `jsp`, `applicationcontext.xml`, `spring-servlet.xml`, `web.xml`

Answer (score -2):

you need to add mysql connector jar to the project classpath as external jar..
then it will work fine :D

Comment: The class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is actually from connector jar, so it is there already ;-)

Comment: he's using maven. so no, he doesn't need to do that.